# Как перенести каждое n слово в отдельную строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть длинная строка с разделителями ;. необходимо каждое 1,4,7,... в 1ю строку, каждое 2,5,8,... во 2ю строку, каждое 3,6,9,.... в 3ю строку

**Оригинал:**

[image]

**Как должно быть:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Убедитесь, что строка заканчивается символом `;`.
- Скопируйте строку дважды
- Выберите первую строку
- Find: `([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)`
- Replace: `\1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Используйте 'Replace all':

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Повторите для других строк с `\2` и `\3`.